# Samsung HDD - Doesn't detect

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have a Samsung external hard disk drive.

It doesn't detect on Explorer.

**System Specifications**

Windows 10 - 64 bit

Dell - Inspiron 14 - 5000 series (i7 processor intel)

**DISK MANAGEMENT**

Sometimes it appears on diskmgmt.msc, but sometimes does not.

Right now it's appearing as "Disk 1 - Unknown - Not Initialised"

[image: Disk Management - not initialised]

**DEVICE MANAGEMENT**

I can see my hard disk under "Disk Drives" as "Samsung M3 Portable USB Device".

**DEVICES AND PRINTERS**

My external hd appears in "Devices and Printers" under "Devices".

But cannot be accessed.

[image: Eject driver - Devices and Printers]

**MINITOOL - PARTITION RECOVERY**

It finds the HDD, but "Partition Recovery Wizard" is not able to recover it.

[image: minitool - partition wizard]

**ALREADY TRIED**

- Using another cable;
- Connecting it in another computer;
- Restarted computer several times;
- MiniTool - Partition Wizard Free;

Comment: If anther computer can't detect it, it's most likely dead/on its way out.

Comment: @BilfredKerman, I've added some pictures, please take a look

Comment: If you care about the data on it, **STOP**. All of the things you are doing present significant risk to the data on the drive. Don't be Cecilia Giménez. (And, by the way, having valuable data on only a rotating, external drive is not a good idea. They're pretty much the least reliable data storage device in common use.)

Comment: OP, does the hard drive make any weird noises when you plug it in, like clicking or scraping? @DavidSchwartz

Comment: Yes, Bilfred, sometimes when I plug it it "beeps" a few (~8) times (not like a nail sound). I have an identical HD and the only different sound I hear is a motor, an engine [from the good one].

Comment: It's dead. Gone. Goodbye. The 'beep' sound you're hearing is most likely directly related to a dead head.

Comment: @BilfredKerman, in this case what are the chances to recover data? What are the possible solutions? I can get an identical hard drive to replace disks, can't I?

Comment: The moment you open the case of the hard drive in the wrong environment, you can pretty much assume all the data that was on it is gone. So you can't replace the disks yourself. The only solution here is for professional recovery, and even then the data may still be lost depending on the damage on the disks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try doing is, in disk management, right click on the drive. If it's not initialised, there should be an option of some kind when you right click it to initialise it. Get the drive to initialise, and it should automatically create a partition and format itself. If it doesn't automatically create a partition, you'll have to make one yourself. See [this](http://www.guidingtech.com/681/create-partition-windows-disk-management/) guide for some guidance on making a partition. Hopefully, if everything goes smoothly, your drive is now working.

Comment: Bilfred, what are the odds? I have sensitive information on this hard drive. I can not lose them.

Comment: If it's not working on any computer, the drives a goner. There's no way to recover the data without first initialising it, other than a professional recovery solution (which can costs hundreds, if not thousands, of dollars). If the initialisation does work, you could try running Recuva on it to see what it picks up, but IMHO I doubt it will even initialise.

Comment: @RafaelVidal If you have sensitive information, you have asked *entirely* the wrong question! The only question you should ask is "How do you preserve valuable information on a drive that appears to not be working?" And the very first rule is **for the love of God, stop messing with it**. Unless you know exactly what you are doing, you risk doing further damage.

Comment: @BilfredKerman Professional recovery is typically under $1,000 now. There's a lot more competition.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I'm aware about the risks and I'm avoiding anything that may prejudice the recovery process. But still I'm trying to get to a solution. Tomorrow, I'll look for an expert on data recovery. Meanwhile, I'm trying "small" things that may resolve.

Comment: @RafaelVidal This is a huge mistake. Every time you apply power to it, for example, you run the risk of digging the heads (further?) into the platter. There are lots of other similar risks.

Comment: I'm aware of that, @DavidSchwartz. My question here is simple: what measures I can take to make my hard drive to work again or to allow me to extract files from it. There is not a lot of money in game, otherwise I would go for a five-star recovery technician; there is no intention to leave HDD untouched and not harm it any more - and certainly do not solve the problem. I respect you and appreciate your attention to the data.